# query mysql with two conditions

Tags: mysql

I am trying to query my database to display only records where atleast 60% of the ordered phones has been received.

Here is a stripped down version of my table:

```
dealID | Ordered | Received | precreditEL    | cancelled  | precredit
1      | 5       | 4        |                |            |
2      | 2       | 2        |                |            |
3      | 10      | 2        |                |            |
4      | 8       | 8        | Non-applicable |            |
5      | 6       | 5        | Non-applicable | Cancelled  | Ready
```

Here is my current query

```
select deals.dealID,customer_info.accName,account_info.accessid,account_info.access_password,customer_info.contactNumber,deals.est_bill,deals.precreditAssigned,deals.precreditEL,deals.precredit
from customer_info join deals
left join account_info  on account_info.custID = customer_info.custID
left join phone_details on phone_details.dealID = deals.dealID 
where customer_info.custID = deals.custID
and deals.precreditEL <> 'Non-applicable'
and deals.precredit <> 'Complete'
and deals.cancelled IS NULL
GROUP BY deals.dealID
having ((100 - (((sum(phone_details.ordered) - sum(phone_details.received)) / sum(phone_details.ordered)) * 100)) >= 60)
```

This works perfectly. The query will give me records that has 60% of the ordered received as long as `precreditEL` is not Non-applicable and its not marked as cancelled. So my result will be `dealID 1 and 2`.

But now I need to add another condition that bypasses this condition. If `precredit` is marked as `Ready` the result will display the record regardless of the condition above. So my result will display `dealID 1, 2 and 5`

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I got it by changing

```
having ((100 - (((sum(phone_details.ordered) - sum(phone_details.received)) / sum(phone_details.ordered)) * 100)) >= 60)
```

to

```
having (((100 - (((sum(phone_details.ordered) - sum(phone_details.received)) / sum(phone_details.ordered)) * 100)) >= 60) OR deals.precredit ='Ready')
```